# How to get the indexPath of a UITableView Row in edit mode

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, editmode

Is there a way to get a row that is in edit mode?

I know I can get it here `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

but how do I get it out side of this method?

`NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];` doesn't work as it returns NULL...

When I mean edit mode that means the row has shifted to the left and shows Delete at the right hand side...

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexPathForSelectedRow` does not work because the row is not selected.

Define a property to hold the current row selected for deletion:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *indexPathOfDeleteRow;
```

Then use `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath` to update the property:

```
- (void)  tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
  forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
        self.indexPathOfDeleteRow = indexPath;
}
```

Comment: Nice and simple.  Excellent.  Thanks

Comment: No need for a dedicated property. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `UITableView` extension:

```
extension UITableView {

    var indexPathForEditingRow: NSIndexPath? {
        return indexPathsForEditingRows.first
    }

    var indexPathsForEditingRows: [NSIndexPath] {
        return visibleCells.flatMap { cell -> NSIndexPath? in
            guard let indexPath = indexPathForCell(cell) where cell.editingStyle != .None else {
                return nil
            }
            return indexPath
        }
    }

}
```